# GCP dataflow - How to validate PCollection data present in lookup table (biq query table)

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

how to implement below data flow in GCP dataflow?

1. Read data from text file
   sample data list of users  `[ {'user' : 'user-1','age' : 10},{'user' : 'user-2','age' : 20}... ]`
2. Read bigquery table and verify 'user' column value present is present in #1 PCollection.
3. return the row if not exist otherwise skip the row.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in Python:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

users_data = (
    p
    | 'Read Users Text File' >> ReadFromText('path/to/text/file.txt')
    | 'Parse JSON to Dict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: eval(x))  # Assuming each line is a valid Python dict string
)

bigquery_data = p | 'Read from BigQuery' >> ReadFromBigQuery(query='SELECT * FROM your_dataset.your_table')

def filter_user(row, users_list):
    return row['user'] not in users_list

filtered_rows = (
    bigquery_data
    | 'Filter Users' >> beam.Filter(filter_user, beam.pvalue.AsList(users_data))
)

filtered_rows | 'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery('your_dataset.your_filtered_table')
```

Comment: In streaming job , beam.pvalue.AsList(users_data) will refresh for every row( 'Filter Users' task ) or one time activity . meaning that work like cache.. it will not refresh

Comment: In your original post, you mentioned "Read data from text file sample data list of users", meaning you're using a Batch job